# Simplest jQuery validation rules example

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, declarative

The following HTML form successfully utilizes jQuery's form validation, displaying "This field is required" to the right of the form field if left blank, and "Please enter at least 2 characters" if fewer than 2 characters were entered.  However, instead of the validation metadata being specified using the class and minlength attributes on the "cname" form input field, I'd like to use jQuery's "rules" API instead, where the rules are specified in the body of the validate function.  Thanks in advance:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="/lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){$("#commentForm").validate(
    /*
     rules/messages here
    */
    );}
    );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found it very helpful

Comment: Closing this question was "questionable"

Comment: Sorry if voting to re-open my question seems self-serving.  I'll rescind my vote if I get a new "platinum" badge for asking a question that got closed but nevertheless gets 100K views (fewer than 12K views to go as of July 2013).  Even if this question gets no more answers, I don't think it should have the "stigma" of being a closed question.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - since it looks like we all got downvoted for closing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568440/is-there-some-preprocessors-for-js-like-less-for-css), have a balancing upvote :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables ah ok I'd never been the victim of a spite downvote before (or if I had I didn't know it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The examples contained in [this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20120108075037/http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2) do the trick.

Comment: I'm being pro-active and adding a link to the article archived on web.archive.org in case the original link ever dies: http://web.archive.org/web/20120108075037/http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2

Comment: You should clean up this link only answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
rules: {
    cname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    }
},
messages: {
    cname: {
        required: "<li>Please enter a name.</li>",
        minlength: "<li>Your name is not long enough.</li>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate your effort.  However I was not able to get it to work.  I actually tried something pretty much just like this several times before, that is why I posted here on SO.  Am editing original question to indicate location of HTML files I've uploaded to one of my sites

Comment: Ok, there needs to be a comma at the end of the rules block, before the messages block, and curly braces around both blocks.  This rectifies simple Javascript errors, and I've updated the HTML-2 file online, but the validation still does not work :(  I'm sure it's simple, just need to get past this

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
     cname : { required : true, minlength: 2 }
    }
});
```

Should be something like that, I've just typed this up in the editor here so might be a syntax error or two, but you should be able to follow the pattern and the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 0):

The input in the markup is missing `"type"`, the input (text I assume) has the attribute `name="name"` and `ID="cname"`, the provided code by Ayo calls the input named "cname"* where it should be *"name"*.